# mouse speed javascript function

Tags: javascript, performance, cursor

Working on some javascript. I found a pretty good function that calculates the speed of the cursor. The problem is that i want to return the actual value, not a callback. How would you do that?

```
        function makeVelocityCalculator(e_init, callback) {
        var x = e_init.clientX,
            y = e_init.clientY,
            t = Date.now();
        return function(e) {
            var new_x = e.clientX,
                new_y = e.clientY,
                new_t = Date.now();
            var x_dist = new_x - x,
                y_dist = new_y - y,
                interval = new_t - t;
            // update values:
            x = new_x;
            y = new_y;
            t = new_t;
            var velocity = Math.sqrt(x_dist*x_dist+y_dist*y_dist)/interval;
            callback(velocity);
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well , then change that function to return velocity, instead of "callback(velocity)"

[Js Fiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/rainerpl/DACtg/)

Or you can use it the way it was intended

```
makeVelocityCalculator(initialEvent, function(velocity) {
   console.log("velocity is", velocity);
});
is pretty much same as 
var velocity = makeVelocityCalculator(initialEvent);
console.log("velocity is", velocity);
```

Comment: hm, if i do:

var velocity = makeVelocityCalculator(event);
console.log("velocity is", velocity);

i get velocity is function()

i want the actual value of velocity.

Comment: that example was assuming you already changed the function to return velocity as shown above

Comment: tried that one. But it gets error on the other event in the return  function (e)

Comment: i made a js fiddle sample

Answer (score 1):

```
 function calculateVelocity(e_init) {
    var x = e_init.clientX,
        y = e_init.clientY,
        t = Date.now();
    return function(e) {
        var new_x = e.clientX,
            new_y = e.clientY,
            new_t = Date.now();
        var x_dist = new_x - x,
            y_dist = new_y - y,
            interval = new_t - t;
        // update values:
        x = new_x;
        y = new_y;
        t = new_t;
        var velocity = Math.sqrt(x_dist*x_dist+y_dist*y_dist)/interval;
        return velocity;
    };
}

var velocity = calculateVelocity(e_init)(e);
// OR
var v_f = calculateVelocity(e_init);
// then some code ...
v_f(e);
```

Use an immediately invoking function `(function(){})()` if you want the call to `calculateVelocity` to return the velocity, otherwise return the function, which in turn returns the velocity.

Comment: @user2952238 Yeah I didn't read the code too thoroughly the first time, try the modified code.